# compare model value in controller with database value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to update my model in the `POST` of my controller:

I'm getting the original values from the database here:

```
var origAttributes = (from tAttr in db.TeacherAttrs where tAttr.ID == ta.ID select tAttr);
```

I have a property in the my `ViewModel` that is a type of `db.TeacherAttr`

> property name: `ta.DMTeacherAttr`

I'm wondering is there a way to compare the values between what my model (`ta.DMTeacherAttr`) has and what is in the database already?

I am using Entity Framework 5 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
var origTeacherAttr = db.TeacherAttrs.Find(ta.ID);

if(origTeacherAttr.DMTeacherAttr==ta.DMTeacherAttr)
{
//Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of comparing is to see what fields exactly needed to be updated then Entity Framework will do it for you, and you need to do two things :

1. Map your ViewModel to your Model
2. Set all your Model properties to virtual

Entity Framework will wrap your classes with a proxy and will track their properties .